# Can I say "foxy" for a man?

Tags: word-usage

A dictionary says that *foxy* can be used to refer to a sexy woman.
Can I also use this word for a sexy man?

Comment: No, because a sexy man is not necessarily a sexy woman.

Comment: Maybe you can use 'Hunk'.

Comment: It makes the man sound rather weaselly.

Comment: Even if there's an obscure meaning, implication or usage that may be flattering, with the predominantly one feminine and another pejorative senses in which it is more commonly used, it would first strike a negative note before anything else. So beware. Just my 2c.

Comment: Why the close votes?

Comment: "Foxy" for a woman means she is sleek and good looking like a fox.  "Foxy" for a man means he is sly and sneaky like a fox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My dictionary reads:

> "**foxy** (*adj.*) (chiefly of a woman) sexually attractive."

So I suppose you can. But whether it will be regarded as a compliment or an insult really depends on who you are talking to, and how you say it. It may [raise eyebrows](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/What-does-it-mean-to-raise-eyebrows) either way.

Comment: Thanks. I know foxy also means cunning. But maybe I can call my boyfriend "Foxy" as a sexy guy, just between him and me.

Comment: @TKCP a "silver fox" (a man with more salt than pepper in his hair) is a compliment.

Comment: It's interesting that you didn't reveal the context until just now. You didn't say if you were a man or a woman, or that if you were talking to or about a stranger or a significant other. In future questions, I recommend including as many details as you can, so that you'll get better answers and fewer close votes. (Oh, and if it's  just between you and him, and you mean it as a compliment, my guess is that he'll take it as a compliment. But this is not [interpersonal.se] ~ lol.)

Comment: As JR said. That info better be included in the body of the Q.

Comment: @J.R. "Your" dictionary?

Comment: @TKCP 'Foxy' does not mean cunning at all. It pretty much only means  what JR gave from the dictionary. A fox certainly is used as a metaphor for cunning or cleverness, but 'foxy' does not have those connotations at all. That may not make much sense, but that's just how the words are used.

Comment: @Kris - "My dictionary" was only meant to refer the first one I happened to first check (in this case, the Dictionary app that comes standard on Mac computers). Because the OP's question begins, "A dictionary says...," I was intentionally terse and vague. I was trying to emphasize a point: one shouldn't consult a single dictionary when trying to figure out the full nuances and limits of a word. In this case, some dictionaries specifically associate the word with women, while others simply say, _"Sensually attractive; sexy."_ The more dictionaries we check, the more we can learn.